# Unable to add a Service Reference to any WCF Service

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, .net-3.5

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1 on .NET 3.5 SP1 on Vista

Any time I try to add a Service Reference to any WCF service I get an error that says "Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultImportOptions' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel,Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=..."

This happens when I try to connect to either a local WCF service or one running on the internet.

If I create the blank WCF Service Library and hit run, it brings up the WCF Test Client as expected and then errors out with the same error showing in its error dialog.

I've Googled this issue and found several references to people having the same issue, but none with a definitive fix.  Some suggested uninstalling .NET 3.5 and reinstalling, which I did, but it didn't seem to help.

I even uninstalled .NET 3.5 SP1 and replaced it with just .NET 3.5 and still get the same behavior.

I tried to uninstall ALL of .NET, but after I uninstall 3.5 I see no way to uninstall .NET 3 or 2.  They show up in the list of programs, but there is no option to uninstall them.  I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2008/08/01/8803442.aspx) article with explicit instructions for removing it all in Vista, but the pieces to remove for .NET 2 and 3 don't show up as stated.

All of the other .NET stuff seems to work fine.  I haven't run into any issues with ASP.NET development or anything else - connecting to a WCF service seems to be the only issue.  This is what I'm focusing on currently in my studies though.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by just re-installing VS 2008 SP1.  After the install and the reboot stuff seems to be working properly.

Whew!